# With automatic UITableViewCell height in iOS 8, is it possible for it to work if the cell's contents are embedded in a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

My `UITableViewCell` subclass has several `UILabels` in it of varying length, and with iOS 8 and Auto Layout constraints in the cell the height is now automatically configured and cell heights can be dynamic.

However I want to embed all the contents of the cell in another `UIView`. Is it possible for the cell's height to still be dynamic? As in the `UIView` that the cell contents are embedded in will grow and shrink automatically based on the content and thus the cell will as well? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic height works by performing an Autolayout pass on the cell's content view. As long as the constraints are in place for a height to be calculated, the specific view hierarchy should be irrelevant.